# Failed to add fields.Selection to parent model

Tags: security, inheritance, odoo-10

I'm working on access restriction to res.partner.
Currently I have two questions:

1.Why does this code don't create new field to inherited model (first error was something like "unknown object _", now it's gone): (Now it works, first question is answered)

```
from odoo import models, fields
class partner(models.Model):
    _inherit = 'res.partner'
    privacy_visibility = fields.Selection([
            ('followers', _('On invitation only')),
            ('employees', _('Visible by all employees')),
         #error was here. according to odoo documentation, here is a comma
         #if you remove it, the code works: [![enter image description here][1]][1]([('',''),('',''),('','')])
        ],
        string='Privacy', required=True,
        default='employees',
        help="Holds visibility of the partner that affects currently logged user:\n"
                "- On invitation only: Employee may only see the followed partners\n"
                "- Visible by all employees: Employee may see selected partner\n")
```

2. Later, when my restrictions would be applied, how to make selected users to access all pertners anyway? (my ideas - 1.to hide "privacy_visibility" field to be visible in developer mode only, as it made for project's "sub-task project". 2.to create a new group, but I have no idea how to use access groups with row-level access), which way wold you recommend to go?

---

Comment: If you are interested in the question: my code didn't work. I have made the another module with defferent names and same logic and it works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First Question Ans:
The Selection field syntax is not correct please follow this syntax

Example:

> gender = fields.Selection([('male', 'Male'), ('female', 'Female'), ('any', 'Any')], string='Gender')

Comment: According to documentation, there is a comma after last pair  ..('any', 'Any'),].. but I have changed my code according to your answer. The last error I have: "Column res.partner.gender is not exist". After module reinstallation everything works.

Answer (score 1):

You are calling the translate object (the underscore "_") to translate your selection values, but you did not import it.

Change:

```
from odoo import models, fields
```

To:

```
from odoo import models, fields, _
```

Comment: My code didn't work even as simple as this: gender = fields.Selection([('male', 'Male'), ('female', 'Female'), ('any', 'Any'),], string='Gender'). I suppose the key to error is extra comma after Any')